# Advanced Colorpicker for Firefox Extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, color-picker

I am using default [color picker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/colorpicker) for my Firefox extension but it is pretty simple. Users ask to have an advanced 16 million color picker. Is there any other advanced alternative for default color picker of Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in [Firefox 27](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/27) you will be able to use [`<html:input type="color"/>`](http://html5tutorial.info/html5-color.php) which uses a more advanced color picker.

Comment: This is excellent news indeed!  But if I incorporate this feature into my add-on will that make version 27.0 the compatibility range floor?

Comment: It is not working for Firefox 27 but for Firefox 30. Documentation says it is OK for Firefox 27?

Comment: OK, dom.forms.color needs to be set "true" to see advanced color. It uses OS color picker and opens the color picker related to left top corner of window. I would like to have a position adjustment method, too.